# powershell script with only variables running but the variable dont "catch"

Tags: powershell, unix, ubuntu-18.04

I have a script1.ps1 that has inside it scrip2.ps1 with the following lines :

```
echo *****blabla*****
$hostName = "host1"
$statip = "192.168.3.1"
$subnet = "255.255.255.0"
$gateWay = "192.168.3.254"
```

Inside script1.ps1 I run it this way:

```
cd /home/user/
& ./script2.ps1
```

When I run it  I see on my terminal *****blabla*****.

But when I try to echo the rest of the variables  - I don't get nothing. Not even null.

If I'll copy the commands and past them it will work.

Comment: You need to [dot source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) the call to the second script for variables, functions, etc to appear in the scope of the first script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by using:

```
Get-Content '<fullpath>/script2.ps1' | Invoke-Expression
```